# What does t bag mean?

Tags: terminology

After reading some [terminology](/questions/tagged/terminology) questions I felt the need to add to the collection the term "t bag" / "t-bag" / "teabag". It is often heard and seen, usually but not limited to multiplayer games.

So, what does it mean and where did it originate from?

Comment: It should be limited to multiplayer as it's a vulgar way of, let's say, disrespecting other players after you've killed them. Of course you can do it to NPC's but it's not the same. I believe this originated in Halo multiplayer games.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill I phrased it that way because while I agree, I didn't felt like excluding the few people who use it in single player games.

Comment: This feels like something that would be trivial to find online - heck, if I search the word "teabag" in Google, I get an Urban Dictionary result that explains this, long before I get any actual purchasable teabags for making my morning cuppa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Teabag (your spelling may vary) refers to sitting on a defeated player's face or body and standing up right after, multiple times in a row.

The specifics depend on the game. For instance, in some games you'd crouch, in others you'd lie down. You still have to stand back up soon after, and repeat the process multiple times for the same person.

The victim doesn't have to be an opponent (though, usually they are), and they don't have to have been defeated by you.

Regardless, it is a fairly vulgar and disrespectful way of treating the defeated and is widely considered to be an insult.

Comment: In it's conception it was meant to further annoy your dead foe by placing your virtual avatar's nuts on their dead face. I believe the first tea-bags were always seen by the dead player's camera for few seconds.